# How to check multiple radio buttons in array loop in php

Tags: php, html

I have fetched data and show in the radio buttons while the radio buttons are in loop, and insert the data in loop too.

The problem is that I can check only one radio button from the form, for each question one radio button must be check, which I can't.

[image: layout]

```
<form  method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<?php 
$count=1;
$que="SELECT * FROM addques WHERE quz_id='$var'";
$dbd=mysqli_query($conn,$que);
    while ($cmd=mysqli_fetch_array($dbd)) {
            $quest=$cmd['qusname'];
            $ans_id=$cmd['ans_id'];
            $opt1=$cmd['qpta'];
            $opt2=$cmd['optb'];
            $opt3=$cmd['optc'];
            $opt4=$cmd['optd'];
            $answ=$cmd['answer'];?>
<b>Question &nbsp; <?php echo $count++;?>&nbsp;:<br><?php echo $quest;?></b><br><br>
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="ansid[]" value="<?php echo $ans_id; ?>">
<input type="radio" name="ans[]" value="1"><?php echo $opt1;?><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ans[]" value="2"><?php echo $opt2;?><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ans[]" value="3"><?php echo $opt3;?><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ans[]" value="4"><?php echo $opt4?><br><br><br>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
<?php
$i=0;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
while ( $i<$noquestions  ) { 
$query="INSERT INTO `result`(  `quz_id`, `ans_id`, `answer`) VALUES('";
$query.=$var .  "', '"; 
$query.=$_POST['ansid'][$i] .  "', '"; 
$query.=$_POST['ans'][$i] .  "' )";
$db=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$i++;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: please see image for better understanding   (Layout) in start of my problem statement

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting that bug is you have given `name="ans[]"` so each time the index value incrementing.

You can fix it by giving the following code

```
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="2">
```

And so on.

You have been using radio button inside a loop so you can use it by setting a loop variable like `name="ans[$i]"`

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="ans['.$i.']" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="ans['.$i.']" value="2">';
```